# How to open webview in popupwindow in android?

Tags: android, android-webview, popupwindow

I want to add web view in PopupWindow in my android application.This is only working for alert dialog.
And this is my code:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle("Google");
            WebView wv = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
            wv.loadUrl("http:\\www.google.com");
            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);

                    return true;
                }
            });

            alert.setView(wv);
            alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }
```

But I want to do this with popup window.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and what problem are you facing

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: See my code above. I want to open url in webview either in alert dialog or popup window but I am not able to do this so far. I am a newbie . Please guide.

Comment: @SilviGupta You can customize your PopUp Window and inflate your layout which will include your webview

Comment: You may need to write your own WebChromeClient..

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
            WebView wv = (WebView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.web);
            wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);

                    return true;
                }
            });

            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
            Dialog markerPopUpDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
            markerPopUpDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

and this is layout.main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</WebView>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I want. I want to directly redirect to the url without this small window which is appearing till the url loads.

Comment: @SilviGupta Your code is right. So what is the issue ?

Comment: I am getting the title and close button in a dialog but I am not able to load the url.

Comment: @SilviGupta I got your issue. When you load your url it is showing only close button and Google text and after url loaded it is showing in full screen. Is it?

Comment: Exactly but what's the solution? Can I add progressbar to it

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using activity also. first you need to make an activity with web view and set layout width and height in java file with below code....

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width*0.9),(int)(height*0.8));
```

and in Android Manifest file select theme "@style/AppTheme.CustomThemeForWebViewPOPUp" for this activity and in style file put this code....

```
<style name="AppTheme.CustomThemeForWebViewPOPUp">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/popup_activity_design</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you should customize your alert dialog with custom view.

**Make one xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    </WebView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prg"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|right"
    android:text="Close" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now implement code in java file:

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alert.setTitle("Google");
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.file_name, null);
    alert.setView(view);

    WebView wv = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    pb = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.prg);
    Button btnClose = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    alertDialog = alert.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Also make custom `WebViewClient`

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);

        if (pb.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        System.out.println("on finish");
        if (pb.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note :** Declare `alertDialog` object as a global.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have done it. Here is my code if somebody need to do this.

```
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle("Terms and conditions");
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.layout_termsdialog,null);
            WebView wv = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.web);
            progressbarterms= (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressbarterms);
            wv.loadUrl("my url");
            WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.setWebViewClient(new TermsClient());
            alert.setView(view);
            alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }
class TermsClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    progressbarterms.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                    progressbarterms.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

And layout file contains webview and progressbar.

Comment: I have posted answer with Progress bar. It was right too. You could use that one !